# How to include external HTML in my .aspx page from a JSP+JSTL equivalent

Tags: html, asp.net, .net

I have this code in JSP+JSTL (Java) to insert some HTML into the page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:set var="caasPath" value="http://wwww.MyExampleSite.com/header/default"/>
<c:import url="${caasPath}/header?contentType=html"/>
```

I need to do the same but in ASP.NET Web Forms (.aspx file). I have tried with an .ascx but I don't know how to insert html directly in the page without using an iframe.

Here is an example from MSDN about how to convert the Java code and use Web Form Controls http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478990.aspx

What is the Asp.Net (.aspx) equivalent to this code?

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
<%@ Register Src="http://wwww.MyExampleSite.com/header/default/header?contentType=html" TagName="header"  Tagprefix="cta" %>
<cta:header ID="headerSection" runat="server"/>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is not a nice 1-liner available to you.  But you can create a method (lets call it 'dotnetImport') that makes a web request and call it like so:

```
<%= dotnetImport("http://wwww.ExampleSite.com/header/default/header?contentType=html"); %>
```

where dotnetImport is defined:

```
public string dotnetImport(string address) {
  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (address);
  request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
  Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
  string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
  // dispose the above... use best practices to avoid memory leaks.
  return responseFromServer;
}
```

Disclaimer, I didn't test this, it is meant to be a starting point, not a ready-to-go-paste-in solution.

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks for this great answer @Mikey. But, is there any other way to include it directly in the HTML without using code behind or java script?

Comment: Do you want the server to make the request for the additional content, or the client?  You can use javascript/jquery to have the client make the request.  If you want the server to make the request and include the result in the page that is sent to the client, then you have to use some sort of server-side code.  You can do this with code-behind (e.g. aspx or via a re-usable user control .ascx) or if you want to avoid code behind you can do it by making the request with inline server tags in the HTML. http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx